# How to remove a custom view and rearrange linear layour

Tags: android, android-activity

First of all I will explain my scenario.

I have an activity with a linear layout and I am inflating that linear layout with custom views. In the custom view I have a remove button to remove the particular child.

I know to remove the view I have to add an onClick Listener to the button in the custom view. But what I am not sure about is that how can I remove the view from its parent view from that onClick Listener.

I am populating the linear layout from items stored in shared preferences. So I thought first to update the shared preference by removing the string of the particular custom view I am clicking. But I don't know how I cn manage to re-populate the linear layout, since the function is in the parent activity.

I am a complete newbie in android. Thanks in advance

### update

I'll make the scenario a little more simple.

I have a custom view with two imagebuttons - update & remove.

If i click in the remove button, then the custom view should be removed from the linearlayout.

And if I click in the update imagebutton, a function of the Activity which hosts the Linearlayout should be called with the text in the customview as a parameter.

How can i do this. I tried many ways, but failed :-(

Comment: you can remove by parent.removeView(childview); method.

Comment: Use GONE and Visible properties of View

Comment: Can't use GONE, sine I want to remove that entry - not hide.

Comment: I got the remove method. Thanks @piyush-gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer finally :

For the first requirement, ie., to remove the view, I used:

```
LinearLayout parentLyt = (LinearLayout) RecentSearch.this.getParent();
parentLyt.removeView(RecentSearch.this);
```

Thanks Very much to Piyush Gupta (@piyush)

For the second option, to access the hosting activity, I used `getContext()` and casted it to my activity class, then called the method.

Thanks every one who replied.